# If I want to get data from sales_order_grid table, which CollectionFactory I should use?

Tags: magento2, order-grid

If I want to get data from **sales_order_grid** table, which CollectionFactory I should inject?

for example:
If I want to get **Sales_order_item**, I should use

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory $itemCollectionFactory,
```

so
If I want get data from **sales_order_grid**, which CollectionFactory I should use?

IS there any documentation I can learn the difference of those different Collection Factory? Thanks

I just showing my code below, but I have no idea why magento saying
**"has an error: Call to undefined method Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection\Interceptor::create(). [] []
"**

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as SalesOrderGridCollection;

    /**
     * @var SalesOrderGridCollection
     */
    private $sOGcollection; 


    public function __construct(

        SalesOrderGridCollection $sOGcollection
    ) {

        $this->sOGcollection = $sOGcollection;
        


     public function getSalesOrderGrid()
        {
            
        try {
            $itemData = $this->sOGcollection->create();
                $currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // Y-m-d h:i:s
                $newDate = strtotime('-30 MINUTE', strtotime($currentDate));
                $newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newDate);
                $itemData->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', ['gteq' => $newDate]);
                $itemData->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', ['lteq' => $currentDate]);
                $itemData->load();
            return $itemData;
            
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }   


$SalesOrderGride = $this->getSalesOrderGrid();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest, Try this class,
\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory

if this will not work please let us know your requirement/problem in detail, so I can help you to get the correct information.

Comment: I finally used this Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\CollectionFactory